# Accuracy rate of Keras neural network not changing

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I am a complete newbie to Neural Networks and keras and I am trying to build a neural network classifier using Keras to predict gender on the basis of height. When I run the following code, the accuracy does not improve upon each iteration and the predicted class is always 0.

Since this is a homework assignment, the professor has opted to keep the data private, but my data merely consists of a pandas DataFrame with two columns: gender and height where gender is coded as a string of 'female' and 'male' and height is a number in inches.

```
from __future__ import division
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import operator
import numpy
import pandas
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

# encode class values as integers
def encode_Y(Y):
    encoder = LabelEncoder()
    encoder.fit(Y)
    encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)
    return(encoded_Y)

def NN(X_data):
    seed = 7
    numpy.random.seed(seed)
    X = X_data.values.astype(float)
    Y = train["gender"].values
    #change Y from ['female', 'male'] format to 0, 1 encoding
    encoded_Y = encode_Y(Y)
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=1, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(10, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
    opt = SGD(lr=0.001)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics ['accuracy'])
    model.fit(X, encoded_Y, batch_size=10, nb_epoch=150, verbose=0)
    return model

height_model = NN(train["height"])

def acc_rate(model, dataX, dataY):
    train_pred = model.predict_classes(dataX.values.astype(float)).flatten()
    encoded_Y = encode_Y(dataY)
    return sum(train_pred == encoded_Y)/len(train_pred)

acc_rate(height_model, train["height"], train["gender"])
```

Possible problems/approaches I have tried:

1. My data is pretty balanced. The proportion of females and males are almost perfectly split 50%, so this should not be an issue.
2. Changing the learning rate (I have tried 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, and 0.0001).
3. Changing the optimizer.

Comment: How much data do you have? Change your model.fit call verbose setting to 1 and nb_epochs to like 10 to see what is happening after each epoch. What is the loss? Posting some of your output might help.

Comment: have you tried changing the activation functions? 

Other than that, why using a NN for this task? It's classifying data that contains only one linear feature. You just need a linear classifier.